# How to symbolize line feature like the picture with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a line featureclass, I want to symbolize as pic attached, all the number are different fields of the feature, I just don't know how to make the arrow box, with white and black part.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP2HJ.jpg]

Comment: I suspect you'll need to extend the current highway shield code to produce that automatically. Otherwise look at an SVG symbol with a text label over top at a fixed point on the line